# Why does <= can be applied to Int and Long, but == can't?

Tags: kotlin

I am curious why I can apply `<=` to both Int and Long, but `==` doesn't work. See [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/NwY5iRiQZ):

```
fun main() { 
    val a = 0L
    
    if (a == 0) { 
        // Compile error (Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Long' and 'Int')
    }
    
    if (a <= 0) { 
        // No compile error
    }
}
```

Comment: As a more general point: consider that two numbers can be strictly unequal without one being greater or less than the other: for example, consider the BigDecimals ‘1’ and ‘1.000’. It's rare; the Java docs for [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) call this behaviour ‘inconsistent with equals’, and strongly recommends against it (as it can have unexpected effects), but there are some cases where it makes sense. The situation here, with different types, isn't _quite_ the same, but seems similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<=` works simply because there is a [`compareTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/compare-to.html) overload defined in `Long` that takes `Int`:

```
class Long {
    // ...
    operator fun compareTo(other: Int): Int
    // ...
}
```

`<=` is simply translated to a call to this (plus a comparison of the returned `Int`).

While `==` also translates to a call to `equals(Any?)` (with additional null checks), there is [this bit in the spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#value-equality-expressions) that disallows comparing the quality of things of completely different type:

> If type of `A` and type of `B` are definitely distinct and not related by subtyping, `A == B` is an invalid expression and should result in a compile-time error.

Comment: Also from the link you posted: Informally: this principle means “no two objects unrelated by subtyping can ever be considered equal by ==”.

Answer (score 3):

When comparing Int and Long values using `==` in Kotlin, the compiler will perform a type check and will determine that the types are not compatible. Therefore, it is not possible to compare Int and Long values using `==`. There is no implicit widening conversions for numbers in Kotlin due to its [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/numbers.html#floating-point-types).

However, the `<=` operator is used for comparing numeric values, and ****it is overloaded** for both Int and Long types**. When comparing Int and Long values using `<=`, [Long#compareTo()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/compare-to.html) method is being called. As you can see in [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/compare-to.html), it can accept both Int and Long types as Parameters.